# Jssor Slider not working in IE7 GetComputedStyle

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jssor

I got a problem with Jssor Slider in IE 7, console shows following error:

```
Jssor.Slider.min.js, Line 2 character 8364.

Property GetComputedStyle is null or not define
```

JS Code:

```
 if (data.url == 'pdf' || data.url == 'articulo'){
                        var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
                        var drag = 0;
                        if (isiPad == true || document.getElementById('index-movil')){
                            drag = 1;
                        }
                            var options = {
                                $DragOrientation: drag,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                                $Loop: false,
                                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                    $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                                }
                            };



                        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);}
```

Chrome, Firefox and Safari working perfectly

Thanks...

Comment: No such problem found. If possible, please post your code here.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Edit my post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, it works OK. Maybe you are not using the latest version.

Btw, you can set $Loop to 0 instead of false.

$Loop: Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I'm using the last version, also I've changed the loop and don't worked.

Comment: Please use jssor.js + jssor.slider.js to see what's the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've get fix my problem, in jssor.slider.min.js (only works at less IE9) I've changed GetComputedStyle to currentStyle.